# Reciting the parshiyyot of the tefillin on Tish'ah BeAv

Tags: torah-study, tefilin, tisha-bav

Some have the custom to read all four *parshiyyot* contained in the *tefillin* while wearing them. (See e.g. [Mishnah Berurah 25:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.25.16?lang=bi).)

It is forbidden to learn Torah on Tish'ah BeAv, but one may recite Torah passages that fall under the rubric of daily prayers (*seder hayom*). ([Shulchan Aruch 554:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.554.4?lang=bi))

Is reciting the the *parshiyyot* of the *tefillin* while wearing them (at *mincha*) included in this category?

I'm aware that [Mishnah Berurah 555:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.555.5?lang=bi) rules not to say these paragraphs. Are there dissenting opinions?

Comment: much of davening is made of Torah passages (sh'ma, pesukei d'zimra etc). Are you starting by making a distinction between parts of "davening" and "torah sections some people have the minhag of reciting"? Or are you asking about any and all?

Comment: I suppose I am asking whether such a distinction exists. Shulchan Aruch seems to imply that passages which are unequivocally part of the daily prayer service (such as the scriptural passages of *korbanot*, *eizehu mekoman*, *rabbi yishma'el*) may be recited. Does that extend to a other passages that (at least some) people have the custom to recite daily?